# Application not installed in android error

Tags: android

I have made application in Netbeans7.1.2 .
my application working perfectly in emulator which is configured android 2.1 but after copying bin folder in Android device(tablet) that gives error "Application not installed".
what is this problem plz if someone know about this ?

Answer (score 2):

Copying `bin/` folder is not sufficient enough to warrant an install.

You can do it this way:

Use the Android's SDK tool called `adb` to install it directly on to the device. For example, suppose your package-name in your project is called **org.foo.bar.app** and an apk file is generated and called **foobar.apk** (This will be found in the `bin/`) folder typically, or where you specify Eclipse to generate the apk, via from within Eclipse:

- Right click on project
- Click on *Android Tools*
- Click on `Export the unsigned Application Package`

**OR**

- Click on `Export Signed Application Package`.

Then:

Plug in cable to device, and issue the command from within `Windows Cmd` or `Linux Terminal`, in this manner, `adb install foobar.apk`

To uninstall an app from the device, specify the package-name, like this `adb uninstall org.foo.bar.app`

Comment: thanks it resolved..... i have another problem when i retrieve exist data into same place where that was than i am fail to get data into spinner(combobox).  how to get data into combobox like combobox.setText(c.getString(0)); i know it is wrong function but how to get it ?